# touchswipe js firing right direction event on jquery resize stop action - (non touch only)

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery.touchswipe.js 1.6.6.
On one laptop (with touch) everything is fine.  But on a laptop without a touch screen I see this behavior...

repro

1. create a jqueryui resizeable object
2. drag the resize handle
3. stop resizing

   - triggers the stop handler on my resizeable object
   - (non touch device) also triggers the swipe event with the 'right' direction

any ideas why?

Comment: Please upload an exemple or a jsfiddle

Comment: i don't see a simple way to isolate it into jsfiddle since my laptop has a touch screen at the moment.  was just hoping someone had some insights.